# Firefox 31.1.0 not playing some H.264 videos

Tags: firefox, ffmpeg, h.264

I have two h264 video files. One is "big buck bunny" the other is one I have created using ffmpeg. Both play in most browsers, but in Firefox 31.1.0 "big buck bunny" plays fine, but my video gives a "corrupt video" response.

The outputs from ffprobe for the two videos in tuen are given below (bunny first, then mine)

Can anyone see why mine will not play...?

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'mov_bbb.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42isomavc1
    creation_time   : 2012-03-13 08:58:06
    encoder         : HandBrake 0.9.6 2012022800
  Duration: 00:00:10.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 629 kb/s
    Chapter #0:0: start -0.080000, end 10.000000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 1
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m/smpte170m/bt709), 320x176, 300 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2012-03-13 08:58:06
      encoder         : JVT/AVC Coding
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 160 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2012-03-13 08:58:06
    Stream #0:2(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 160 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2012-03-13 08:58:06
    Stream #0:3(und): Subtitle: mov_text (text / 0x74786574), 0 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2012-03-13 08:58:06
```

```
 
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'test.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
  Duration: 00:00:09.92, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 159 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 352x288 [SAR 12:11 DAR 4:3], 157 kb/s, 12.50 fps, 12.50 tbr, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
```

Comment: `12.50 fps` major red flag. show encoding command

Comment: ffmpeg -v 0 -y -i tmp.mp4 -ss 1 -t 11.5 -r 12.5 -c:v libx264 -preset medium -threads 8 -crf 28 test.mp4     This doesn't give any errors, and seems to work in most browsers, including most versions of FF. I think it may be related to using FF in a virtual machine. I can try an integer FPS though and see if it helps

Comment: what if you try with -r 25

Comment: No joy on either 12 or 25. Works fine in most browsers though....may just be the virtualisation the browser doesn't like

Answer (score 1):

You could try encoding your video in ffmpeg with the option `-movflags faststart` see [here](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#toc-Options-5)

This will move the moov atom to the start of the file preventing the need to download the entire file before playback is possible

Other than that all I can suggest is trying [MP4Box](https://gpac.wp.mines-telecom.fr/mp4box/) to encode your video

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. No joy I'm afraid...since it only seems to affect one version of Firefox I'm not too worried...but it is a bit strange.

Comment: It looks like it may have something to do with running FF inside of a VMWare virtual machine....